# Adding items to below gridview when dropped on top gridview

Tags: silverlight, drag-and-drop, telerik, radgridview

On my main page, I have a button and telerik mainRadGridView. When I click my button, I get a popup which is divided it into two regions left and right.

On left, I have a RadTreeView and on right, I have a popupRadGridView.

Initially when my popup is open, the popupRadGridView is disabled. When I drop from left to right for first time in my popup nothing is added to popupRadGridView since it is disable which is correct.

But when I drop for second time on to my disabled popupRadGridView inside my opened popup, there is an element **added to my mainRadGridView on my main page which is wrong**.

I cannot understand how to stop adding onto my main page. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check for the e.Options.ParticipatingVisualRoots in Drop Event of GridView - should provide you the no of active opened child windows participating in the operation.

For additional information follow this link

[Telerik Silverlight](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/raddraganddrop-child-window-non-telerik-popups.html)

Comment: Thanks, I did something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue as below

In my mainpage codebehind. I did like below

```
void mainRadGridView_OnDropInfo(object sender, DragDropEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.Options.ParticipatingVisualRoots.Count > 0)
      {
        return;
      }
    else  
    { 
      do stuff;
    }
}
```